# Phonegap / Cordova / jquery not connecting Internet

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I have a small app to test:
https://github.com/vmbelizario/phonegap
its just a login form who connects to a PHP page and check if the login exist.

The side-server is the auth.php file.
The client-side is the js/auth.js who connect to http://myserver.com/auth.php (example) and do the login test.

If i upload in a apache + mysql server, works.
But in android, after put the credentials i got only "connecting..." and didnt worked.
I tested via adobe builder (build.phonegap.com/apps) build and install in my smartphone and via monaca.io android emulator.
Can someone check what is wrong and help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Cordova Whitelist plugin installed.

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
This is required for Android and not on iOS or Browser.

Then check your config.xml for lines like these.

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

This will allow any network communication from your app. To be more safe you can change this to.

```
<access origin="YOUR_URL/*" />
```

This will allow network access only the the URL specified and any subdomains.

See the documentation here.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the query string in the url. Try to concatenate the URL with your data string and pass it as a complete url in your ajax call. First try to hit the complete URL with static values in the browser, if it works then that's a solution for your problem. For example: `http://myserver.com/auth.php?callback=?email=example@mail.com&password=password&login=`